# Extracting text nodes or elements with relative XPath in Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, scraper

So I'm relatively new to using XPath and I am having a little difficulty honing in on the exact syntax that I need to use for my specific application. The scraper that I have built is working perfectly fine, (when I use a less complicated path it works). Once I try to get more specific with my path, it isn't returning the proper values.

A simplified model of the document structure that I am trying to manipulate is

```
<table class="rightLinks">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://wwww.example.com">Text That I want to Grab</a>
      </td>
      <td>Some</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://wwww.example2.com">Text That I want to Grab</a>
      </td>
      <td>Some</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://wwww.example3.com">Text That I want to Grab</a>
      </td>
      <td>Some</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://wwww.example4.com">Text That I want to Grab</a>
      </td>
      <td>Some</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Basically, I would like to grab the href values and the text with the links.

This is the portion of my scraper regarding this and what I have tried so far:

```
  import scrapy
  from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
  from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

  def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//table[@class="rightLinks"]/tbody/tr/*[1]/a'):
      item = DanishItem()
      item['company_name'] = sel.xpath('/text()').extract()
      item['website'] = sel.xpath('/@href').extract()
      yield item
```

Edit: new paths I'm using

```
def parse(self, response):
  for sel in response.xpath('//table[@class="rightLinks"]/tr/*[1]/a'):
    item = DanishItem()
    item['company_name'] = sel.text
    item['website'] = sel.attrib['href']
    yield item
```

Final Edit: Working code (thanks guys!)

```
 def parse(self, response):
  for sel in response.xpath('//table[@class="rightLinks"]/tr/*[1]/a'):
    item = DanishItem()
    item['company_name'] = sel.xpath('./text()').extract()
    item['website'] = sel.xpath('./@href').extract()
    yield item
```

Any suggestions or hints would be much appreciated!

Joey

Comment: Are you sure your *real* HTML looks this way? One way people often get messed up is looking at HTML in a browser when writing their XPath, rather than at (say) literal output from `curl`. Browsers munge the DOMs -- your real HTML may not, for instance, actually have a `tbody` element at all.

Comment: By the way -- is this lxml you're using, or something lxml-derived such as BeautifulSoup? (In the future, it might be a good practice to specify the library as a tag).

Comment: I'm using Scrapy with lxml, I removed the /tbody from my path and still can't seem to get it to return anything. I also took @CharlesDuffy's suggestion and used sel.text and sel.attrib['href']

Comment: Got it to work! (See above edits) Thanks guys!

Comment: If your real solution isn't what I suggested, by the way, feel free to actually add it as your own answer -- generally, answering things yourself is preferred over editing an answer into a question.

Comment: (...and, indeed -- my answer would have been right for pure lxml or for BeautifulSoup, but scrapy does its own thing and behaves differently).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sel.xpath('/text()')` and `sel.xpath('/@href')` are both absolute paths; if you wanted relative paths, this would be `./text()` or `./@href`.

If this is lxml -- and `sel` is an lxml `Element` object -- just use `sel.text`, or `sel.attrib['href']` -- no XPath needed.